# “Newest” vs. “Latest”

Tags: meaning, word-difference, superlatives

In a case like “latest video” or “newest video”, which one is right? I have seen “newest” used on stackoverflow.com:

[image]

According to the online dictionaries I checked, “latest” = “most recent” and “newest” = “of recent origin, production, purchase, etc.”

So just wondering which one is the right one when describing a video that just came out.

Comment: Have you looked up *latest* and *newest* in a dictionary? What did you find unclear?

Comment: I looked it up on the OP's behalf. Here is what I found in [a dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/latest): ***latest*** (adj.) most recent, or newest. Should we conclude that they are always interchangeable? (Because I don't think so, though I think they are both okay in the OP's example.)

Comment: I checked in some online dictionaries. so according to dictionaries latest=most recent; newest = recent origin, production, purchase, etc. so which one is the right one to use in sentences like i specified in my question? Damkerng T.: What is "OP"?

Comment: @ChiyaanSuraj OP usually means either "original post" or "original poster". In my comment, I meant the latter (i.e. you, who originally posted this question :-). By the way, welcome to ELL!

Comment: I’ve made some edits to your question to incorporate more of the explanation you gave in your comment. It can help to include links and direct quotes when referring to specific dictionary definitions. In this case, it looks like the problem might be that you are comparing the definition of “latest” with the definition of “new”.

Answer (score 2):

In colloquial English they're synonymous, at least as you've use them.

"Have you seen the latest Kapoor video?" and "Have you seen the newest Kapoor video?" would mean the same.